# UEFI System. Are EFI settings kept on the HDD. What happens if I change HDD?

Tags: hard-disk, uefi

I have an UEFI system with Linux installed on it. Unfortunately I need to upgrade the BIOS firmware and after a month of failing with live CDs and Live DOSes and so on I have decided to buy a new hard drive, put Windows on it, and upgrade bios from there.

Are the EFI settings saved on my old hard drive? Would I be able to change hard drives and boot my Linux installation without issues afterwards? Would installing windows on my new hard drive add EFI entries that would become corrupted when I swap back my old drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the Windows/Linux installation with EFI, the installer puts a startup file onto a special partition on the disk.  This EFI partition is usually mounted under `/boot/efi` in Linux.  The EFI partition (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is a FAT partition containing the OS's boot subsystem, e.g. `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi`.

The EFI settings in NVRAM are read by the UEFI upon boot and contains pointers to the files in this partition.  This acts like a boot manager with different options, like GRUB (albeit GRUB itself is sometimes called by it).  Therefore an OS will add an entry in the EFI NVRAM for itself which will point to its files on the EFI partition, e.g. `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`.  The efi boot manager can be configured under Linux with the `efibootmgr` command, or in your BIOS setup.  In both you can also set default boot entries.  Manipulating these entries may be more difficult with the "Secure Boot" BIOS option enabled.

In your case there will be invalid entries in the EFI boot manager (NVRAM area) once the HDD is removed.  However, your new OS will install (and likely set as default) its newly installed option in the EFI boot manager.

Comment: Thanks! So basically it is going to keep my entries and when swapping back the hard drive I just need to change back to the valid ones?

Comment: Yes, that is probably going to work.  Of course, some "cleanup" function of the BIOS or the Windows installer could remove invalid entries (my BIOS does not).  I suggest using `efibootmgr` (or `efibootmgr -v`) and/or the BIOS to list the current boot options, and make a note of their contents.  Then see whether your BIOS allows for the manual addition of entries (mine does).  This way you have a recovery route should some software be smart and remove your entries...  (See also https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr for usage options of `efibootmgr`.)

Answer (score 5):

EFI settings are stored in NVRAM, typically some flash on the motherboard (part of the flash chip which stored the motherboard's firmware, including the UEFI itself). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) for more details.

So you can safely change hard drives without losing EFI settings.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a danger then that when installing windows on the new hard drive it will wipe out my EFI settings needed to boot linux on my old hard drive?

Comment: It will probably alter your boot manager settings, but if you switch hard drives again your boot manager will notice and ask you what to do. You should always be able to recover and boot the system.